# Need to reconnect external display several times

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, kde, thinkpad, usb-c

I'm running (K)ubuntu 18.04.2 and I connect an external monitor to one of my laptop's USB-C ports.

Sometimes (it's really random...) I have to turn the display off and on again (or disconnect and reconnect it) several times before it's recognised, whereas sometimes it is recognised immediately.

What's really weird is that when it's not recognised (and by that I mean, it doesn't even appear when running `xrandr`), the mouse and keyboard work fine, although they are connected to the monitor's USBs. Also, I charge the laptop through the screen, and that works fine too even when the display itself doesn't work.

Here my `inxi` output:

```
System:    Kernel: 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.12.7 (Qt 5.9.5) Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: LENOVO product: 20L8S05C00 v: ThinkPad T480s serial: N/A
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 20L8S05C00 serial: N/A UEFI: LENOVO v: N22ET48W (1.25 ) date: 07/18/2018
Graphics:  Card: Intel UHD Graphics 620 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 2560x1440@59.99hz, 2560x1440@59.95hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.2.8 Direct Render: Yes
```

and here is my (filtered) `xrandr` output with the monitor working:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   2560x1440     60.01 +  59.99    59.99*   59.96    59.95  
(...)
DP-1 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
(...)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Another weird behaviour is that if I close my laptop lid and only then disconnect the external monitor (which causes the laptop to go to sleep), the laptop primary display will remain off when I resume from sleep by opening the lid. I've found no way to reactivate it apart from connecting an external monitor again or rebooting, which is quite annoying...